# error about android studio activity?

Tags: java, android

I was trying to run a sample code While launching the application in the android 1.5 emulator , I got these errors.... Any one have some hint..?
ERROR from LogCat:

```
12-03 08:17:41.221 2141-2141/com.example.umairkhan.test1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.umairkhan.test1, PID: 2141
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.umairkhan.test1/com.example.umairkhan.test1.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{b3e8b0d 2141:com.example.umairkhan.test1/u0a57} (pid=2141, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{b3e8b0d 2141:com.example.umairkhan.test1/u0a57} (pid=2141, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
at com.example.umairkhan.test1.MainActivity.fetchContacts(MainActivity.java:38)
at com.example.umairkhan.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The key line seems to be: _Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{b3e8b0d 2141:com.example.umairkhan.test1/u0a57} (pid=2141, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS_

Answer (score 0):

As error suggest

> requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

you have to add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

For more information about `android-permissions` visit [android developer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/permissions/declaring.html)

**[Permissions](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)**

hope it will help.

Comment: @umairkhan what is logcat after you put this two permission. is it same or different error is coming this time? can you please check?

Comment: can not put it in comment coz its too long

Comment: dont put it just check it :)

Comment: yes you have top put all appropriate permissions in manifest file otherwise it wont work.